# What is the correct way to update images with has_many_attached in Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage, ruby-on-rails-6

I have a Rails 6 app that uses Active Storage to store multiple images to a model (Activity) with `has_many_attached`.

I don't understand how to append extra images instead of replacing the existing images. When I upload images the first time they save correctly. However, when I update the record, and I add a new image, the previous images are replaced by the new image. In Rails 5 the new image would be appended without replacing the previously saved images.

How do I append a new image instead of replacing the previous images?

I have an Activity model that has the following:

```
has_many_attached :images
```

In the form I have:

```
<%= f.file_field :images, multiple: true %>
```

In the controller I have the following:

```
def update
  @activity = Activity.find(params[:id])

  if @activity.update(activity_params)
    flash[:success] = "Saved"
    redirect_to activity_path(@activity)
  else
    flash[:error] = "Not saved"
    redirect_to edit_activity_path(@activity)
  end
end

private

  def activity_params
    params.require(:activity).permit(:name, images:[])
  end
```

Comment: here is a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58282845/rails-6-active-storage-could-not-find-or-build-blob-expected-attachable-got

Comment: I ended up using the answer from the above comment.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is the solution that I have now:

Add this to the update action:

```
if params[:activity][:images].present?
  params[:activity][:images].each do |image|
  activity.images.attach(image)
end
```

So, the entire update action looks like this:

```
def update
  if activity.update(activity_params)
    if params[:activity][:images].present?
      params[:activity][:images].each do |image|
        activity.images.attach(image)
      end
    end
    flash[:success] = 'Updated!'
    respond_with activity, location: activity_path(activity)
  else
    flash[:error] = 'Not updated'
    respond_with activity, location: activity_path(activity)
  end
end
```

And remove this from permitted params:

```
images:[]
```

Comment: How could the create action be set up?

Comment: just to complement a little with some information, if you change `params[:activity][:images]` to `activity_params[:images] ` it will not work

Comment: A bit late to the party but assuming you're on Rails 6 this seems to be the culprit: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61933070/how-to-edit-multiple-attached-images-using-activestorage-has-many-attached-in

Answer (score 2):

This happens cause assigning to attachments declared with `has_many_attached` since Rails 6.0 replaces any existing attachments by default.

Details:

- https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#default-values-for-target-version-6-0
- https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/6_0_release_notes.html#active-storage-notable-changes

So, in Rails 6.0+ you need to add this line to your environment config (`config/environments/development.rb`, etc.):
`config.active_storage.replace_on_assign_to_many = false`
After app restart previously added attachments won't be replaced.

Comment: Alternatively, call `attach()` rather than assigning, as in the accepted answer.

Comment: ⚠️ DEPRECATION WARNING: config.active_storage.replace_on_assign_to_many is deprecated and will be removed in Rails 7.1

Answer (score -5):

Try selecting multiple files like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/EqaU7.png
If it works then you will need to select all previous images while uploading new one which does not sound good. You may like to use nesting forms.

Comment: The question here is: How do I append a new image instead of replacing the previous images? In Rails 6 the way to update multiple images for a given record has changed since Rails 5. Based on your answer you may not be familiar with this issue.